# match variable name in reading each line of a file to create view ddl

Tags: perl

I have an input file,

> ```
>                   TableName1.Column1
>                   TableName1.Column2 
>                   TableName2.Column1
>                   TableName2.Column2
>                   TableName3.Column3 etc
> ```

I would like it read each of the line and distinguish what columns belong for TableName1 so I can build a view ddl like this:  CREATE VIEW TABLENAME1 AS SELECT Column1, Column2 From TableName1; and Next will be View TableName2 etc.

```
my $file = "summary.csv";
open (my $FH, '<', $file) or die "Can't open '$file' for read: $!";
my @lines;
while (my $line = <$FH>) {
  push (@lines, $line);
}
close $FH or die "Cannot close $file: $!";

my $ln=@lines;


for (my $x=0; $x<$ln; $x++){
  print("---Start->\n") if($x == 0);
  print "---------------->\n";
  my $first = (split /\./, $lines[$x] )[0];
  my $second = $first;

  print "Second is: $second \n";


  if ((split /\./, $lines[$x] )[0]  eq $first )
  {
    print "Same Table: $lines[$x]";

  }
  else 

  {
    print "Next Table: $lines[$x]";

  }

  print("---End-->\n") if($x == $ln -1);
}
```

Comment: I am not able to create the select list as I can't detect pattern of fields for that table1 and so forth. How do I do that?

Comment: I've fixed the indentation in your code. You're welcome, of course, but please consider doing it yourself in the future. Careful indentation is a powerful tool for understanding code and if you're asking a large number of people to study your code, it's only polite to make that as easy as possible for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it something like this.

Parse the data into a data structure. I'm using an array of anonymous arrays. In the anonymous arrays, the first element is the table name and any other elements are columns.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @tables;

my $curr_table = '';

# Note: I used a DATA filehandle to test this. You'll need to
# insert your file-opening code here.

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my ($table, $column) = split /\./;

  if ($table ne $curr_table) {
    push @tables, [ $table ];
    $curr_table = $table;
  }
  push @{ $tables[-1] }, $column;
}
```

And then walk the data structure to do whatever you want with the data (here, I'm just displaying it).

```
for my $t (@tables) {
  my ($table, @columns) = @{ $t };

  say "Table: table";
  say " * $_" for @columns;
}
```